# How do you use websites such as icons8 for iOS mobile application, using Xcode 6?

Tags: ios, user-interface, icons

I am trying to use icons for my tab bar from icons8.com, but when I download it, the icon seems extremely pixelated. What's the correct way of downloading and using the icons for your iOS mobile app? With all the clarity and sharpness as shown on the website. I am using Xcode 6, objective-c.

Answer (score 1):

1 - The icon should have the same dimensions as your image (You can find guidelines of the recomended sizes here:[iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html))

2- You should have one icon for each screen density with the right dimensions: icon.png with thesame sizethatyou choose in 1, icon@2x.png with twice that size and icon@3x.png tree times that size.

Comment: Thank you for the response but could you elaborate on what you mean by the icon should have the same dimensions as my image? Is the icon you are referring to the icon downloaded from icons8.com? If so then what would be my image? An example would be great using the icons8.com icon. What size should I download from there for tab bar icon to choose in 1? Thanks again in advance!

Comment: Please help if you can

Comment: For example for the tab bar if you follow the guidelines on the link i posted the icon.png should have "About 25 x 25" for ipad mini. 50 x 50 for icon@2x.png and 75 x 75 icon@3x.png.

Answer (score 0):

You can download icons up to 100x100 px for free on Icons8. For 25x25, download 25x25, 50x50, and 75x75. Add them all to Xcode.

If you're a paid user, you can use a single PDF version; Xcode generates all PNGs on compilation then.